# JSONLoader fails in THREE.js

Tags: json, three.js

I will import a json file with three.js.
At the moment I used the syntax described in the docu:

```
function _loadJSON(path) {
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load(path,
        function (geometry) {
           scene.add( geometry );
        }
    );
}
_loadJSON('models/Fishnet_JSON.json');
```

The file has been successfully loaded. But it occurs an error message (firefox):

**TypeError: n is undefined**

In google chrome it is written:

**three.min.js:384 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

What does this question mean?

I checked my json file with an validator and it is valid

Comment: Have you already tried the ObjectLoader?

Comment: If I use ObjectLoader instead of JSONLoader I get another error: **TypeError: b is undefined** (firefox), **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined** (chrome)

Comment: have you tried importing via a mesh into the loader? https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2015/07/27/importing-blender-modelized-mesh-in-threejs.html

Comment: also, check the type of json, depending on how it was exported it might require an alternative function. see here: https://clara.io/learn/user-guide/data_exchange/threejs_export